# Debug SmsManager within Android SDK emulator

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator

I'm testing a 3rd party application within the Android SDK emulator, which is designed to send out an SMS text message for registration. I don't have the source code for this application but is it possible to use a debugger with the emulator to intercept the call to SmsManager and determine what information is being sent and to what destination?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the source code, all you can do is watch adb logcat output. Also you can use "adb logcat -b radio" to watch any modem commands. for example, you will see the following if you are trying to send a sms. It depends on what you want to debug.

```
    D/AT      (   29): AT> AT+CSQ
    D/AT      (   29): AT< +CSQ: 7,99
    D/AT      (   29): AT< OK
    D/RILJ    (   95): [0058]< SIGNAL_STRENGTH {7, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    D/RILJ    (   95): WAKE_LOCK_TIMEOUT  mReqPending=0 mRequestList=1
    D/RILJ    (   95): 0: [19] SET_NETWORK_SELECTION_AUTOMATIC
    D/SMS     (   95): SMS send size=0time=1353001019635
    D/RILJ    (   95): [0059]> SEND_SMS
    D/RIL     (   29): onRequest: SEND_SMS
    D/AT      (   29): AT> AT+CMGS=13
    D/AT      (   29): AT< > 
    D/AT      (   29): AT> 00010004815545000004e432990c^Z

D/AT      (   29): AT< +CMGS: 0
D/AT      (   29): AT< OK
D/RILJ    (   95): [0059]< SEND_SMS { messageRef = 0, errorCode = 0, ackPdu = null}
D/SMS     (   95): SMS send complete. Broadcasting intent: PendingIntent{44c8c118: android.os.BinderProxy@44c8c0e0}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't provide me the information that I'm looking for - specifically, the content and the destination of the text message. What I was looking for is a way to somehow set a breakpoint in SmsManager class (in android.jar) and inspect the variables when this is called. Is this possible using eclipse/ADT?